# Presto array contains an element that likes some pattern

Tags: sql, presto, trino

For example, one column in my table is an array, I want to check if that column contains an element that contains substring "denied" (so elements like "denied at 12:00 pm", "denied by admin" will all count, I believe I will have to use "like" to identify the pattern). How to write sql for this?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome

Answer (score 35):

Use presto's [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html):

- `filter()`, which returns elements that satisfy the given condition
- `cardinality()`, which returns the size of an array:

Like this:

```
where cardinality(filter(myArray, x -> x like '%denied%')) > 0
```

Comment: You could `reduce(myArray, false, (a, x -> a OR x like '%denied%'))` to avoid copying an array for every row.

Answer (score 18):

In newer versions of PrestoSQL ([now known as Trino](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), you can use the [`any_match`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=any_match#any_match) function:

```sql
WHERE any_match(column, e -> e like '%denied%')
```

Answer (score 1):

See array operator [docs here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)

`contains(array_column,'denied')`

Comment: this does not answer the question. According to the doc, the `CONTAINS` operator only looks for exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

We can use strpos(returns starting position of substring and 0 if not found) here. ([documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html))

```
where strpos(array_column,'denied')>0
```