# Select values from Presto column that contains an element of the array

Tags: sql, presto

Desired output is somewhat reversed version of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766928/presto-array-contains-an-element-that-likes-some-pattern).

Let's say we have table 'letterstable' with letter column.

```
**letter**
a
b
c
ddgas
awdawaa
bdb
acchds
```

I have a query that matches rows from letter column with array elements but what I want to do is to match if any element of arrays 1 or 2 likes letter. Desired output from query below in this case would be:

```
+---------+----------+
| letter  | category |
+---------+----------+
| ddgas   |        1 |
| awdawaa |        1 |
| acchds  |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

Query:

```
with categories as(
  select category, names from(
    values
      ('1', ARRAY['aa', 'bb', 'cc']),
      ('2', ARRAY['dd', 'ee'])
  ) as t (category, names)
)

select
  letter, category
from letterstable
join categories on cardinality(filter(names, x -> x like letter)) > 0
```

Comment: You should use https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match (available since Presto 317), as it will perform significantly better.

Comment: Also, you can `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(names)` and do a regular join. -- this becomes important if you have many categories.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it looks like I have a older version so any_match isn't supported and cross join unnest methods fails as there is too much data so it reached query limit

Comment: Which Presto version are you on?