Arel query generation for array containment check in Athena/Presto
I'm working on enhancing a report configuration system to support filtering by an array column partition_ids. We want to check if any of the specified partition IDs are present in this array.
Currently, we have a configuration like this:

filters:
  and:
    some_column:
      operator: in
      value:
      - '3'
      - '479'
      - '482'

We want to support a new configuration for array containment:
filters:
  and:
    partition_ids:
      operator: array_contains
      value:
      - 'value1'
      - 'value2'
      - 'value3'

I implemented an array_contains operator in our query builder:

when 'array_contains'
  unnest_alias = Arel::Table.new(:t)
  Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('UNNEST', [arel_table]).as('t(partition_id)'),
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(unnest_alias[:partition_id].in(Array(value)))
  )

However, when testing this with Athena/Presto, I get the following error:
Error Message: line 49:30: mismatched input 'INNER'. Expecting:expression
This suggests that the generated SQL is not compatible with Athena/Presto. How can I modify this Arel code to generate SQL that works with Athena/Presto for checking if any value in an array column matches any value in a list?

See https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766928/presto-array-contains-an-element-that-likes-some-pattern.
